# login using popular account

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, authentication, helper

I want to make easy registration using one of the users account (Facebook or Google or something else).Are their any "LoginHelpers" exist for the most popular accounts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing you wnat to know about is called Oauth.

There is a lot of information about how to do this already, and I'm pretty sure nuget packages to include it in your mvc project for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can search for what's called OAuth authentication. There are many different endpoints, it's up to you to decide what endpoints you want to offer.

Here's an article with a well documented example showing MVC3 and Facebook OAuth authentication.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/206707/Simple-net-MVC-3-web-application-with-integrated-f

---

There are also many prepackaged libraries that offer simple OAuth to many popular services. A "widget" of sorts.

This blog lists several along with some pro's and con's.

http://blog.marcmezzacca.com/2012/03/social-authentication-for-net-a-library-comparison/